Are Gable vents needed on bothe ends to be effective
One side of a colonial does not have a gable vents and the other side does the side without vent the siding doesn't hold.paint as well would installing a gable vents be helpful

What other vents are there?  Most times you want an intake and exhaust so air can move.  Size of the vents are important also.  The paint not holding might be from damp air staying on that side or outside factors like not enough drying(shade/no sun) when painting.

Yes, generally you want two vents of one type or another—one to allow air in, the other to allow air out.  Could be two gable vents, soffit (eave) vents plus ridge vent, or some other combination.

In addition to what Huesmann said, some roofs have O'Hagens or Dormers. O’Hagens are almost flush with the top of the roof, while dormers stick out as the roof pitches down. The single gable vent could also be the "out" sucking from vent blocks under your eve. Those are the horizontal blocks with holes and wire mesh you see between the top of the wall and the bottom of the roof. Whatever you find as built, rule of thumb is that more attic ventilation is better. Also is the entire attic open and able to be vented with one system or is it divided somehow? Inadequate attic ventilation is right up there with leaks as far as destroying roof framing. I will follow with some references to the O'Hagen, Dormer, and Vent Block.

Dormer  https://www.homedepot.com/p/Gibraltar-Building-Products-24-in-x-12-in-Galvanized-Steel-Half-Round-Dormer-Vent-BH24-1-8/310198015

O'Hagin. I was misspelling the name  https://ohagin.com/products/

Vent Block  https://www.lowes.com/pd/22-5-in-L-Brown-Wood-Soffit-Vent/3460098

Please [edit] these links into your answer. Comments can be deleted and the info lost.

... and update your spelling.

How do those O'Hagins even work?
